# Font not showing but when resize it is showing

Tags: css, font-face

It is weird, the fonts are not showing after a refresh, but when resize it is showing. I'm using Open Sans from google.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&text=Hello%20World' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And it is also showing when I unselect the font-family in developers' style tool

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
  color: inherit;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: btw it says, OTS derived font not Open Sans Glyphs. I've red some articles, they said this is the way of webkit in processing custom fonts. they are putting first the text into transparent color when the font files are still loading. But in my case, it is already loaded but still webkit is not turning the texts back to normal. They are still hallow.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this  tag, it's working for me:

```
<link href='http://goo.gl/GkJMjq' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```